# How to deploy a Docusaurus website to Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, docusaurus

I built a production-ready Docusaurus website using `docusaurus build` (or `npm run build`). How can I deploy it to Google App Engine as a static website?

Comment: Why is this downvoted , it's a good question......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your project root folder, create an `app.yaml` file with the following contents:

```yaml
# runtime could be anything, it won't create any instances as everything is static
runtime: python38 

handlers:
  # static files with a URL ending with a file extension
  # (e.g. favicon.ico, manifest.json, jylade.png)
  - url: /(.*\..+)$
    static_files: build/\1
    upload: build/(.*\..+)$

  # index page
  - url: /
    static_files: build/index.html
    upload: build/index.html

  # anything that ends with a slash (e.g. /docs/)
  - url: /(.*)/$
    static_files: build/\1/index.html
    upload: build/(.*)

  # anything else (e.g. /docs)
  - url: /(.*)
    static_files: build/\1/index.html
    upload: build/(.*)
```

Then, create a `.gcloudignore` file:

```
# ignore everything
/[!.]*
/.?*

# except for the build folder
!/build/**
```

Last, run the following command to deploy the site:

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml --project <YOUR GCP PROJECT>
```

Comment: awesome example!